# JQuery / Javascript Submenu Hover Problem

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu, jquery-animate, jquery-hover

I have a problem in a jquery dropdown menu. In my example (link in the bottom) I want that when I hover the Submenu the color of the current menu item (item 2) stays in hover state (color white in example).

I want this in jquery/javascript and not css.

[Link To Live Example](http://jsfiddle.net) with complete Code

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$("ul.submenu li a").css({'background-color': '#fdfa02'});
$("ul.submenu").css({'background-color': '#fdfa02'});
$("ul.submenu2").css({'background-color': '#fdfa02'});   
$('ul.submenu li a').css('color', '#00FF00');

//change the menu text color on mouse over
$('ul.menu li').hover(function () {    
     $(this).find("span:first a").css({color:'#FFFFFF'});    
},
function () {
    $(this).find("span:first a").css({color:'#000000'});  
});
```

Comment: Could you tell me where you put the code ? In teory with this line of code if you hover the submenu the text in the menu stay white, but if you hover out the submenu, the text stays white, don't change to original state (black), but I could be wrong

Comment: "I want this in jquery/javascript and not css." :P

Comment: There you go, white text bug fixed

Comment: @Sbml: You are wrong! Make the code change inline -- it's clear to see where it should go, as other parts match up with your existing code -- and you will see it working.

Comment: @Sbml: Note that his .css change no longer applies just to the .hovered-only element, but to anything matching `"span:first a"` under it.

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal : I now that "I want this in jquery/javascript and not css" could be funny :) , but with css in jquery I can change the colors for variables controled by what I want...